# Oauth2 Login in Spring Cloud Gateway using KeyCloak

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, spring-cloud-gateway

I implemented oauth2 in Spring cloud gateway using KeyCLoak. Now I want all the request are permitted except those which have "/user" in the url. Following is my security configuration

```
 @Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {

    http
            .cors()
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable()

            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers("**/user/**").authenticated()
            .anyExchange().permitAll()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login();

    return http.build();
}
```

I am expecting when user enter the url "http://localhost:8066/user" it will redirect them to keycloak login page, but it is not working,it is not redirecting to the login page of Keycloak.

Answer (score 0):

Read the doc for `AnthPathMatcher` and more generally what valid ant path are.

My guess is what you want actually is `.pathMatchers("/user/**").authenticated()`